# Explicit construction of Lorentz invariant symbols

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

I'm interested in constructing symbols that are invariant under 3+1D Lorentz transformations, with indices that transform under different representations of the Lorentz group.

For example, if we write the symbol $\sigma^\mu_{a\dot{b}} = (1, \vec{\sigma})^\mu_{a\dot{b}}$, we find that if we have $\mu$ transform under the defining representation, while $a$ and $\dot{b}$ transform under $(1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/2)$, then the symbol is unchanged. Such a symbol is useful because when its indices are properly contracted with objects transforming under the representation above, $\sigma^\mu_{a\dot{b}}$ is able to eat the transformation. This means that in the Lagrangian for e.g. a Weyl spinor $\psi$, the kinetic term $i\psi^\dagger \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi$ is Lorentz covariant.

Once one has a proposed invariant symbol, one can check that the symbol is indeed invariant, usually by looking at the sum of the contractions of respective generators of the Lorentz group with the symbol's respective indices. I'm pretty confident in my ability to do this for a symbol that is handed to me, with however many indices that transform in whichever representations. I also feel moderately good about telling whether a non-trivial invariant symbol with a certain combination of indices exists based on the very basics of angular momentum addition - such as if you asked me for an invariant symbol with two $(1/2,0)$ indices, then I'd tell you that $(1/2,0)\otimes(1/2,0) = (0,0) \oplus (1,0)$ contains the singlet $(0,0)$.

What I'm not confident about is how to *construct* these symbols.  It is not enough to me to be able to verify that the symbol is invariant; I want to be able to predict the form of invariant symbols.

---

How do I algorithmically, with minimal guessing, construct invariant symbols with indices that transform under various representations of the Lorentz group? For concreteness, please show an example constructing the symbol $\sigma^\mu_{a\dot{b}}$.

Comment: I don't know the algorithm they use but this can be done for an arbitrary Lie algebra in Maple: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DifferentialGeometry/LieAlgebras/Invariants